# Snort 3.0 Error: Could not find requested DAQ moduel: pcap

Tags: ubuntu, snort

I am trying to install Snort 3.0 on an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I'm using the manual as a guide for this install. Everything went well and it seems the install went fine, however, at page 6, to test Snort with the default configuration file it wants me to pass `snort -c /usr/local/etc/snort/snort.lua` but I am getting the error `Error: Could not find requested DAQ moduel: pcap` I've spent a few hours yesterday Googling but could not find anything. Now, I am a complete beginner when it comes to Ubuntu. What repository do I need to install to get this going? Thanks!

UPDATE
So I installed pcap from the tcpdump, but that did not resolve it. I am still getting the same error.

```
http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.10.0.tar.gz
```

I passed:

```
wget http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.10.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf libpcap-1.10.0.tar.gz
```

Install went fine.

Then I passed:

```
    /usr/local/bin/snort -V
       ,,_     -*> Snort++ <*-
  o"  )~   Version 3.1.0.0

       ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team
               http://snort.org/contact#team
               Copyright (C) 2014-2020 Cisco and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
               Copyright (C) 1998-2013 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
               Using DAQ version 3.0.0
               Using LuaJIT version 2.1.0-beta3
               Using OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
               Using libpcap version 1.9.1 (with TPACKET_V3)
               Using PCRE version 8.44 2020-02-12
               Using ZLIB version 1.2.11
               Using FlatBuffers 1.12.0
               Using Hyperscan version 5.3.0 2021-02-01
               Using LZMA version 5.2.4
```

Then I passed:

```
administrator@Ubuntu:~/snort_src$ snort -c /usr/local/etc/snort/snort.lua
--------------------------------------------------
o")~   Snort++ 3.1.0.0
--------------------------------------------------
Loading /usr/local/etc/snort/snort.lua:
Loading snort_defaults.lua:
Finished snort_defaults.lua:
Loading file_magic.lua:
Finished file_magic.lua:
    ssh
    hosts
    host_cache
    pop
    so_proxy
    stream_tcp
    smtp
    gtp_inspect
    packets
    dce_http_proxy
    stream_icmp
    normalizer
    alerts
    rewrite
    ips
    stream_udp
    binder
    wizard
    appid
    search_engine
    file_id
    ftp_data
    ftp_server
    port_scan
    dce_http_server
    dce_smb
    dce_tcp
    telnet
    ssl
    sip
    rpc_decode
    netflow
    http_inspect
    network
    http2_inspect
    modbus
    host_tracker
    stream_user
    stream_ip
    trace
    back_orifice
    classifications
    dnp3
    active
    ftp_client
    decode
    daq
    stream
    references
    arp_spoof
    output
    process
    dns
    dce_udp
    imap
    stream_file
Finished /usr/local/etc/snort/snort.lua:
--------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Could not find requested DAQ module: pcap

FATAL: see prior 1 errors (0 warnings)
Fatal Error, Quitting..
```

Please advise. Thank you.

UPDATE

It looks like I already have the latest pcap version.

```
dministrator@Ubuntu:~/snort_src$ sudo apt-get install -y libpcap-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libpcap-dev is already the newest version (1.9.1-3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1 libllvm10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Ran dir and it looks like I got everything installed?

```
administrator@Ubuntu:~/snort_src$ dir
boost_1_74_0            libpcap-1.10.0.tar.gz
boost_1_74_0.tar.gz     libsafec-02092020.0-g6d921f
flatbuffers-1.12.0      libsafec-02092020.tar.gz
flatbuffers-build       LuaJIT-2.1.0-beta3
flatbuffers-v1.12.0.tar.gz  LuaJIT-2.1.0-beta3.tar.gz
gperftools-2.8          pcre-8.44
gperftools-2.8.tar.gz       pcre-8.44.tar.gz
hyperscan-5.3.0         ragel-6.10
hyperscan-5.3.0-build       ragel-6.10.tar.gz
libdaq-3.0.0            snort3-3.1.0.0
libdaq-3.0.0.tar.gz     snort3-3.1.0.0.tar.gz
libpcap-1.10.0          v5.3.0.tar.gz
```

I'm out of ideas...Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same issue. I suggest to use --daq-dir.

For example, my daq installed in /usr/local/lib/daq.

When you run snort, use command:

```sh
/usr/local/snort/bin/snort -c /usr/local/snort/etc/snort/snort.lua --daq-dir /usr/local/lib/daq -i ens33 -l /var/log/snort
```

After testing, I found that if you don't use --daq-dir , my snort will report "ERROR: Could not find requested DAQ module: pcap".

Comment: This was the case with FreeBSD installation too for me.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Snort 3 User Manual](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/releases/download/3.1.16.0/snort_user.pdf) Page 15, 3.2 Building, we need to manually install (and maybe compile) the [libdaq](https://github.com/snort3/libdaq) and set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the install dir. In my environment, I do:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

then finish the snort compilation. everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to reinstall libdaq and snort, but do every step in sudo. I found a [post](https://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=104936.0) solving the same issue but for snort 2. It states at some point, that the `locate daq_dump.so` file was missing as it was also the case for my installation.
By executing every step of the installation in sudo, the file appeared in the daq directory (`/usr/local/lib/daq`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error is that libdaq was compiled before libcap library was installed. (so libdaq was compiled without libcap)

After installing libcap.

Compile libdaq again.
Go in libdaq source directory run a:

```
make clean
./configure
```

Make sure that you see this:

> Build PCAP DAQ module...... : yes

```
make
make install
```

Then compile snort again.
In snort source directory:

```
cd build
make clean
cd ..
./configure_cmake.sh
cd build
make
make install
```

Answer (score -1):

I threw in the towel and installed Snort3 via Docker. Resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I also gave up with the numerous DAQ errors while trying to run make in the snort build directory. (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

The Docker version is much easier to work with.

[Snort resources](https://www.snort.org/resources): Includes video resources for installation for Snort2 and Snort3

[Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ciscotalos/snort3)